# Scalar value function usage in the where clause causing performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sqlperformance

I have a sql query which uses a scalar value function inside the where clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TableName T
WHERE T.SomeID = fn_ScalarValueFunction(100)
ORDER BY T.SomeDate
```

The query takes about 1 minute to execute. However, if I run the following queries separately they run within a second.

```
SELECT fn_ScalarValueFunction(100) = 123

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TableName T
WHERE T.SomeID = 123
ORDER BY T.SomeDate
```

I checked the execution plan and it does a full table scan for both queries.

How can I improve performance of the slow query?

Comment: If you're not in SQL Server 2019(+) then the function can't benefit from inlining. YOu therefore might be better off with an inline table value function.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017. Do you suggest to convert the Scalar function to Table Value function?

Comment: Multi-line scalar function *can* be slow (we don't have the definition here, so impossible to know). Converting to an **inline** table-value function could (likely) give performance benefits.

Comment: The problem of using scalar-valued functions in the where clause has been discussed many times. Search a little - but it's a well-known performance problem. Perhaps the first question you should ask yourself is if your function is really useful and really needed. Many inexperience coders like to modularize tsql far too much, which leads to issues like this.

Comment: In truth, I would not be surprised if SQL Server is running the function against **every** row in the table, and then ordering; hence why it's so slow.

Comment: @Larnu - I suspect this too. Strangely it works fine on another database server having similar database tables.

Comment: IS that instance ising 2019?

Comment: If another database server works better the statistics can also influence run times. Still the best way is to post the function along with some dummy data. This way someone might be able to put the performance back into the function which along with inline apply can yield the required performance.

Comment: @Larnu - it is using 2017

Comment: Converting the scalar function to an inline table function seems to fix the performance issue. Not sure what is the logic behind it though, except SQL is not able to create a correct query plan for scalar function.

Comment: It's been discussed many times, and written about, that multi-line functions perform poorly, @developer . If you do a search, you'll find an abundance of articles on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function call to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T.*
FROM TableName T CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (fn_ScalarValueFunction(100)) v(val)
WHERE T.SomeID = v.val
ORDER BY T.SomeDate;
```

In your version, the scalar function needs to be called for *all* rows in the table -- and that adds overhead.  This version might actually be able to use an index on `SomeId`, if one is available.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this but it is still taking 1 minute to execute. There is no index on SomeId, could this be the issue?

Comment: I have created a non clustered index on SomeId but no luck.

Comment: @developer . . . This is very strange.  How large is the table and how many rows match the `where` condition?

Comment: @developer You are pulling back all columns, so it's probably decided not to use the index. `select *` is usually bad. Do you have `include` columns in the index?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - table has 10,000 rows and 11 rows match the where condition.

Comment: @developer . . . The issue is not the full table scan -- that should not take a minute for 10,000 rows.  It is clearly not the sort.  That means that the issue must be the UDF.  But putting the call in `values()` means that it should be called only once.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a variable to hold the value:

```
DECLARE @ID int = fn_ScalarValueFunction(100)

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TableName T 
WHERE T.SomeID = @ID 
ORDER BY T.SomeDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The query is part of the bigger SQL query so I wont be able to get the data in a variable. Otherwise, it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using an inner join with a sub query to get the result of scalar function only once as below

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TableName T
inner join
(select fn_ScalarValueFunction(100) as 'scalarID')t1
on t.someID = t1.scalarID
ORDER BY T.SomeDate
```

Comment: @developer still taking one minute? Query plan has changed?

Comment: @developer the query plan must show a difference